# how to slide frameLayout using sliding menu

Tags: android, layout, android-fragments, android-framelayout

I have work on sliding menu. I have some problem of this sliding menu.[image]

This is 3 frame layout. and i have Require slide center frame layout like this.

This is my second layout. how can i make this second layout?[image]

Issue is: I have required second screen but in the second layout all frame are slide in right side. My requirement is only second frame move right side.

Comment: Can you share your code so that we can help

Comment: i have use fragment and framelayout and sorry i have not authority to share code.

Comment: You can follow http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/ , we can't help you specifically without your code.

Comment: Why doing big things? You can simply use translate animation. Consider onFling?

Comment: I have use Sliding menu and also use https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu this library. So i cant translate. i have use only inbuilt functionality. @ Rethinavel Pillai